# mvc url parameter overrides model object field with same name in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**TL;DR: If you have a Url parameter with the same name as a model object field, using TextBoxFor (tested also with HiddenFor), you will get the url parameter value, and not the model parameter value, even when specifying the model variable.  My question is why.**

RouteConfig

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

TestModel

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

TestController **(Notice the +5 to differentiate between url parameter and model object field)**

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var testModel = new TestModel { Id = id + 5 };
    return View(testModel);
}
```

Test/Index View

```
@model Solution.Models.TestModel
@Html.TextBoxFor(_ => _.Id) // Incorrectly shows 5 
@Html.TextBoxFor(_ => Model.Id) // Incorrectly shows 5
@Html.TextBox("id", Model.Id) // Correctly shows 10
```

View the site by going to:
/test/index/5

The problem is that the TextBoxFor ends up being 5 for both, and the TextBox ends up being 10.  Why is this different?

Assuming there's some strange interaction with the UrlParameter, I don't understand why the second TextBoxFor has the incorrect value since the model that was passed to the view is specifically referenced.  Why does this happen?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I can't reproduce this! THe response view shows the id passed as parameter for every field

Comment: Not sure if our terminology is different, but do you mean the model object field is being shown for every textbox, or the url parameter is being shown?

Either way, if they are all the same, it's different than mine.  I made a blank mvc project just to get the code for this issue.  I could zip up the probject and put it someplace, not sure where though.

Comment: The Id shows the same to every textbox.

Comment: Duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282577/why-is-my-textboxfor-using-my-route-data.

Comment: Yup, looks like it.  Guess I'm not going to get a good reason why.  Your search skills are better than mine.  Thanks.  Not sure how to close the question.

Comment: @Fals if you want to continue to try to recreate this, make sure you have a url parameter (whether it's defined by optional parameter in the RouteConfig, or if you use id=), and make sure you have a model with a field named "id" and then reference that model field in the TextBoxFor and you should get the value of the url parameter and not the model (make sure they are different).  The post by pero shows that this problem at least is reproducible and not a problem with my environment.