# Remove time from datepicker in Edit mode MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I tried different pieces of code to solve this issue but they don't work exactly how I want. I've tried

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { id="datepicker" })
```

and

changing my TextBoxFor to EditorFor while using jquery

```
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
```

When I do either of these the date returns fine without the time (i.e 4-12-14), however I loose the functionality of my datepicker calendar. If I don't use them my datepicker calendar works fine however I end up with 4-12-14 00:00:00 in my edit textbox.

```
The code from my Model is:

 [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it solved all I needed to do was change the formatting of my textbox to

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LRRRentReviewDate, "{0:d/M/yyyy}", new { id="datepicker" })
```

and my Model date format to

```
[Display(Name = "Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d/M/yyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
```

again I needed to use public nullable in my code for my own purposes. My JQuery was fine and didn't need any alterations.

Comment: this works and it also fixes the problem firefox version 57 caused. specifying format with the textbox

Answer (score 4):

The time component comes from the fact that `DateTime` encodes both date and time, obviously enough, and by default the entire date and time string will be set for values in textboxes. If that's not what you want, then you need to specify that on your model. For example:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Or you can explicitly specify the formatting you want:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "dd-MM-yy", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for even this case `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")`. Still ends up with a time 00:00:00 (the DateTime is nullable  but has a value... not sure if that matters)

Comment: The values for the dates I'm doing TextBoxFor come in the URL thru a GET request... and I see the URL has the `00:00:00` in it... maybe MVC is trying to respect that from the URL since it was posted and redirected? Bizarre!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282577/why-is-my-textboxfor-using-my-route-data this -- ModelState was overriding the Model property formatting... because it just took the value from the URL and put that in the textbox (which included 00:00:00)

Comment: I want to remove completely the default widget and replace it with bootstrap datepicker but  when i click in the input  both open

Comment: You'll need to explicitly set the type attribute to "text".